# What is this thing #2?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I'm posting an another one, hope you will like it.

Clues:

1. Some
2. What does a cat do??
3. One is everywhere but still not God.
4. Brother(or sisters maybe) of pie.

I am looking for two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a specific correction from the OP, the answer is:

> **MU SIGMA** (not merely **GREEK LETTERS** as in my original answer)
>
>  *Some* = a homophone of 'SUM', represented in mathematics by **sigma** (Σ).
>
>  *What does a cat do??* = 'MEW', a homophone of **mu** (μ).
>
>  *One is everywhere but still not God* - this could work for either component: (i) the letter **mu** is the [coefficient of friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Coefficient_of_friction) and therefore present *everywhere* where two objects touch; (ii) the UK chart-topping drum-and-bass duo **Sigma** released a song called '[*Anywhere*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ph_g_7gkz40)' in 2018.
>
>  *Brother(or sisters maybe) of pie* - sigma and mu are both Greek letters, like 'PI' (π), a homophone of 'PIE'.

This would also explain the question's edit history, since I note that the first draft of the question contained the line:

> *An Indian data analytics company* - and there is a data science firm in India whose name actually is **[Mu Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_Sigma)**...

Comment: Stiv you have almost cracked it. The answer is rot 13(Zh Fvtzn vgfrys). Also for hint 3 I have a bit simpler explanation but I might add that in another comment.

Comment: Rest others are correctly explained.

Comment: @LakshaySura I have found two possibilities for that line - I've added both :)

Comment: The first possibility was the intended one. And congrats for cracking another one. The checkmark is yours.